# How to manipulate a huge csv file (> 12GB)?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, bigdata, data-analysis

I am dealing with a huge csv file of approximately 13GB and around 130,000,000 line. I am using python and tried to work on it with pandas library, which I used before for this kind of work. However, I was always dealing with csv files of less than 2,000,000 lines or 500MB previously. For this huge file, pandas doesn't seem appropriate anymore as my computer is dying when I try my code (MacBook Pro from 2011 with 8GB RAM). Could somebody advise me a way to deal with this kind of file in python? Would the csv library be more appropriate?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just read it in chunks, set `chunksize` param in [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table), additionally you could store this hd5f

Comment: What are you doing with the file? Can you represent your work as a one-pass algorithm?

Comment: The file gather 6 months of GPS probe data from some corridor in LA. Each line represent a device detected at a certain time and a certain (Latitude, Longitude) point. Device are named with random ID. I would like to classify the file in regards to the 'ID' column to find which one are repeating the most and plot the associated paths. Thanks EdChum I'll try to use this method. An alternative would be to work with each "daily file" (also available in the database) but this is a restriction because some IDs are appearing through different days. I would prefer to work in the most general case.

Answer (score 0):

In Python I have found that for opening big files it is better to use generators as in:

```
with open("ludicrously_humongous.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        #Any process of that line goes here
```

Programming this way, makes your program read only a line at a time into memory, allowing you to work with large files in an agile manner.